# AJAX - Form submit requires two clicks to take effect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I tried changing the `.click` to `.on('click' ....)` and `.submit`

also tried to add `async: false`

but it takes a second click to call success

Is there anyone who can help? I would be very grateful!

Button (Ajax Trigger)

```
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag l(:button_save), :name => nil, :id => 'time_entry_submit' %>
    <%= link_to_function(l(:button_cancel), "$('#new_time_entry_form').toggle();$('#report_menu_options').toggle();".html_safe) %>
  </p>
```

js.erb

```
$('#time_entry_submit').click(function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).parents('form:eq(0)').attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      window.alert(response);
      location.reload();
    }

  })
  return false;
})
```

When I click a second time
alert shows

```
var flashNotice = $("#flash_notice");
flashNotice.remove();
$("#flash_error").remove();
```

and I put the `console.log` inside the `.click`, and it appears on the second click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using UJS so the js code come from `js.erb` will be send to client when the first time you click the submit button, but that js code is just setup the `click` function to call ajax, it's not triggered, so in the first time it'll not do anything else.

now you could trigger your js code immediately as below

```js
// setup
$('#time_entry_submit').click(function(evt){
  // your code
});

// trigger
$("#time_entry_submit").trigger( "click" );
```

**you should not use UJS in this case**, your js code will be send to client everytime you click the submit button.

you could move your js code into a `.js` file that will be packed into `application.js` by webpack, then your js code will be setup immediately as you load webpage, so it's just only loaded one time.